Get a single work item in azure devops via api
As of now, I have to get the work items details from azure devops via api as I have to used it in the third party app but this doesn't seem to work
This is the API Url I tried to get the work items https://dev.azure.com/testOrgzz/test/_apis/wit/workitems/8?api-version=7.2-preview.3
I'm getting this response even though i have access to all the resources
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd"> <html lang="en-US"> <head><title> Azure DevOps Services | Sign In </title><meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=11;&#32;IE=10;&#32;IE=9;&#32;IE=8" /> <link rel="SHORTCUT ICON" href="/favicon.ico"/> <link data-bundlelength="516093" data-bundlename="commoncss" data-highcontrast="/_static/tfs/M235_20240303.1/_cssbundles/HighContrast/vss-bundle-commoncss-vgKIrce5KeykK4FMEhpmn7zyu-3J73Bx2KsJTMmi4ZaI=" data-includedstyles="jQueryUI-Modified;Core;Splitter;PivotView" href="/_static/tfs/M235_20240303.1/_cssbundles/Default/vss-bundle-commoncss-vuiSc9pHdDbcT8LzK_3fJ2kEsn4_fRqmPx_6IdU0oXHc=" rel="stylesheet" /> <link data-bundlelength="117304" data-bundlename="viewcss" data-highcontrast="/_static/tfs/M235_20240303.1/_cssbundles/HighContrast/vss-bundle-viewcss-vuZc8-qj8Ccsk2Id3aYU0dLxPmsvgd6StlyaYitm0xxU=" data-includedstyles="VSS.Controls" href="/_static/tfs/M235_20240303.1/_cssbundles/Default/vss-bundle-viewcss-vZeWfVvRTo2a7DO4ptMBi0cCBa3W_gjANgU36Es8paWQ=" rel="stylesheet" /> <!--UxServices customizations --> <link href="/_static/tfs/M235_20240303.1/_content/Authentication.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" /> </head> <body class="platform"> <script type="text/javascript"> var __vssPageContext = {"webContext":{"user":{"id":"aaaaaaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaaaaaaaaaa","name":"Anonymous","email":"","uniqueName":"TEAM FOUNDATION\\Anonymous"},"host":{"id":"12151c76-78d9-45df-bc19-5b98a8c97843","name":"TEAM FOUNDATION","uri":"https://spsprodcin2.vssps.visualstudio.com/","relativeUri":"/","hostType":"deployment","scheme":"https","authority":"spsprodcin2.vssps.visualstudio.com"}},"moduleLoaderConfig":{"baseUrl":"/_static/tfs/M235_20240303.1/_scripts/TFS/min/","paths":{"UserManagement/Scripts/Resources":"en-US","Authentication/Scripts/Resources":"en-US","Profile/Scripts/Resources":"en-US","VSS/Resources":"en-US","Account/Scripts/Resources":"en-US"},"map":{},"contributionPaths":{"VSS":{"value":"/_static/tfs/M235_20240303.1/_scripts/TFS/min/VSS","pathType":"default"},"VSS/Resources":{"value":"en-US","pathType":"resource"},"q":{"value":"/_static/tfs/M235_20240303.1/_scripts/TFS/min/q","pathType":"default"},"knockout":{"value":"/_static/tfs/M235_20240303.1/_scripts/TFS/min/knockout","pathType":"default"},"mousetrap":{"value":"/_static/tfs/M235_20240303.1/_scripts/TFS/min/mousetrap","pathType":"default"},"mustache":{"value":"/_static/tfs/M235_20240303.1/_scripts/TFS/min/mustache","pathType":"default"},"react":{"value":"/_static/tfs/M235_20240303.1/_scripts/TFS/min/react.15.3","pathType":"default"},"react-dom":{"value":"/_static/tfs/M235_20240303.1/_scripts/TFS/min/react-dom.15.3","pathType":"default"},"react-transition-group":{"value":"/_static/tfs/M235_20240303.1/_scripts/TFS/min/react-transition-group.15.3","pathType":"default"},"jQueryUI":{"value":"/_static/tfs/M235_20240303.1/_scripts/TFS/min/jQueryUI","pathType":"default"},"jquery":{"value":"/_static/tfs/M235_20240303.1/_scripts/TFS/min/jquery","pathType":"default"},"OfficeFabric":{"value":"/_static/tfs/M235_20240303.1/_scripts/TFS/min/OfficeFabric","pathType":"default"},"tslib":{"value":"/_static/tfs/M235_20240303.1/_scripts/TFS/min/tslib","pathType":"default"},"@uifabric":{"value":"/_static/tfs/M235_20240303.1/_scripts/TFS/min/@uifabric","pathType":"default"},"VSSUI":{"value":"/_static/tfs/M235_20240303.1/_scripts/TFS/min/VSSUI","pathType":"default"}},"shim":{"jquery":{"deps":[],"exports":"jQuery"}},"waitSeconds":30},"coreReferences":{"stylesheets":[{"url":"/_static/tfs/M235_20240303.1/_cssbundles/Default/vss-bundle-ext-core-css-vdl6C9oqaY8jIYGt0fSVzQfhTlc3U3sLKE8T0mcZwW_0=","highContrastUrl":null,"isCoreStylesheet":true}],"scripts":[{"identifier":"JQuery","url":"/_static/3rdParty/_scripts/jquery-3.6.0.min.js","fallbackUrl":null,"fallbackCondition":null,"isCoreModule":true},{"identifier":"JQueryXDomain","url":"/_static/3rdParty/_scripts/jquery.xdomainrequest.min.js","fallbackUrl":null,"fallbackCondition":null,"isCoreModule":true},{"identifier":"Promise","url":"/_static/tfs/M235_20240303.1/_scripts/TFS/min/promise.js","fallbackUrl":null,"fallbackCondition":null,"isCoreModule":true},{"identifier":"GlobalScripts","url":"/_static/tfs/M235_20240303.1/_scripts/TFS/min/global-scripts.js","fallbackUrl":null,"fallbackCondition":null,"isCoreModule":true},{"identifier":"LoaderFixes","url":"/_static/tfs/M235_20240303.1/_scripts/TFS/pre-loader-shim.min.js","fallbackUrl":null,"fallbackCondition":null,"isCoreModule":false},{"identifier":"AMDLoader","url":"/_static/3rdParty/_scripts/require.min.js","fallbackUrl":null,"fallbackCondition":null,"isCoreModule":true},{"identifier":"LoaderFixes","url":"/_static/tfs/M235_20240303.1/_scripts/TFS/post-loader-shim.min.js","fallbackUrl":null,"fallbackCondition":null,"isCoreModule":false}],"coreScriptsBundle":{"identifier":"CoreBundle","url":"/_public/_Bundling/Content?bundle=vss-bundle-basejs-vx38JYf0FTtFkI9k88H54KYCLs9sIP_6xJwgWGnd-xvw=","fallbackUrl":null,"fallbackCondition":null,"isCoreModule":true},"extensionCoreReferences":{"identifier":"CoreBundle","url":"/_public/_Bundling/Content?bundle=vss-bundle-ext-core-vjCrGJd2ZXxlGKsVv7B3hWY-FuFMmxCW3Tcq4LWjQhfc=","fallbackUrl":null,"fallbackCondition":null,"isCoreModule":true}},"webAccessConfiguration":{"isHosted":true,"paths":{"rootPath":"/","staticContentRootPath":"/","staticContentVersion":"M235_20240303.1","resourcesPath":"/_static/tfs/M235_20240303.1/_content/","staticRootTfs":"/_static/tfs/M235_20240303.1/","cdnFallbackStaticRootTfs":"/_static/tfs/M235_20240303.1/","staticRoot3rdParty":"/_static/3rdParty/"},"api":{"webApiVersion":"1","areaPrefix":"_","controllerPrefix":""},"mailSettings":{"enabled":false},"registryItems":{}},"microsoftAjaxConfig":{"cultureInfo":{"name":"en-US","numberFormat":{"CurrencyDecimalDigits":2,"CurrencyDecimalSeparator":".","IsReadOnly":true,"CurrencyGroupSizes":[3],"NumberGroupSizes":[3],"PercentGroupSizes":[3],"CurrencyGroupSeparator":",","CurrencySymbol":"$","NaNSymbol":"NaN","CurrencyNegativePattern":0,"NumberNegativePattern":1,"PercentPositivePattern":1,"PercentNegativePattern":1,"NegativeInfinitySymbol":"-∞","NegativeSign":"-","NumberDecimalDigits":2,"NumberDecimalSeparator":".","NumberGroupSeparator":",","CurrencyPositivePattern":0,"PositiveInfinitySymbol":"∞","PositiveSign":"+","PercentDecimalDigits":2,"PercentDecimalSeparator":".","PercentGroupSeparator":",","PercentSymbol":"%","PerMilleSymbol":"‰","NativeDigits":["0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9"],"DigitSubstitution":1},"dateTimeFormat":{"AMDesignator":"AM","Calendar":{"MinSupportedDateTime":"0001-01-01T00:00:00","MaxSupportedDateTime":"9999-12-31T23:59:59.9999999","AlgorithmType":1,"CalendarType":1,"Eras":[1],"TwoDigitYearMax":2049,"IsReadOnly":true},"DateSeparator":"/","FirstDayOfWeek":0,"CalendarWeekRule":0,"FullDateTimePattern":"dddd, MMMM d, yyyy h:mm:ss tt","LongDatePattern":"dddd, MMMM d, yyyy","LongTimePattern":"h:mm:ss tt","MonthDayPattern":"MMMM d","PMDesignator":"PM","RFC1123Pattern":"ddd, dd MMM yyyy HH':'mm':'ss 'GMT'","ShortDatePattern":"M/d/yyyy","ShortTimePattern":"h:mm tt","SortableDateTimePattern":"yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss","TimeSeparator":":","UniversalSortableDateTimePattern":"yyyy'-'MM'-'dd HH':'mm':'ss'Z'","YearMonthPattern":"MMMM yyyy","AbbreviatedDayNames":["Sun","Mon","Tue","Wed","Thu","Fri","Sat"],"ShortestDayNames":["Su","Mo","Tu","We","Th","Fr","Sa"],"DayNames":["Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday"],"AbbreviatedMonthNames":["Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec",""],"MonthNames":["January","February","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November","December",""],"IsReadOnly":true,"NativeCalendarName":"Gregorian Calendar","AbbreviatedMonthGenitiveNames":["Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec",""],"MonthGenitiveNames":["January","February","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November","December",""]},"numberShortForm":{"QuantitySymbols":["K","M","B"],"NumberGroupSize":1000,"ThousandSymbol":"K"},"eras":null}},"timeZonesConfiguration":{},"featureAvailability":{"featureStates":{"VisualStudio.Services.Contribution.EnableOnPremUnsecureBrowsers":false,"VisualStudio.Service.WebPlatform.ClientErrorReporting":false,"Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Gallery.Client.UseCdnAssetUri":false,"VisualStudio.Services.WebAccess.SubresourceIntegrity":false,"VisualStudio.Services.IdentityPicker.ReactProfileCard":true}},"appInsightsConfiguration":{"enabled":false,"instrumentationKey":"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000","insightsScriptUrl":null},"diagnostics":{"sessionId":"c3346a50-2005-48c7-ab99-14f9bb4d09a1","activityId":"c3346a50-2005-48c7-ab99-14f9bb4d09a1","bundlingEnabled":true,"webPlatformVersion":"M235","serviceVersion":"Dev19.M235.1 (build: AzureDevOps_M235_20240303.1)"},"navigation":{"topMostLevel":"deployment","area":"","currentController":"Signin","currentAction":"Index","routeId":"LegacyWebAccessRoute","routeValues":{"controller":"Signin","action":"Index"}},"globalization":{"explicitTheme":"","theme":"Default","culture":"en-US","timezoneOffset":0,"timeZoneId":"UTC"},"serviceInstanceId":"951917ac-a960-4999-8464-e3f0aa25b381","hubsContext":{},"serviceLocations":{"locations":{"951917ac-a960-4999-8464-e3f0aa25b381":{"Application":"https://spsprodcin2.vssps.visualstudio.com/","Deployment":"https://spsprodcin2.vssps.visualstudio.com/"}}}};</script><script type="text/javascript"> var __cultureInfo = __vssPageContext.microsoftAjaxConfig.cultureInfo;</script> <script type="text/javascript">if (window.performance && window.performance.mark) { window.performance.mark('startLoadBundleOuter-basejs'); }</script> <script data-bundlelength="127542" data-bundlename="basejs" src="/_public/_Bundling/Content?bundle=vss-bundle-basejs-vx38JYf0FTtFkI9k88H54KYCLs9sIP_6xJwgWGnd-xvw=" type="text/javascript"></script> <script type="text/javascript">if (window.performance && window.performance.mark) { window.performance.mark('endLoadBundleOuter-basejs'); }</script> <script type="text/javascript"> require.config(__vssPageContext.moduleLoaderConfig);</script> <input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="FJG81vvsBPN1oWz_cBvThEFBMcDuUIWjDXPqE-5Bz_Uv882aOolthNQn8HRkz9NliIO4VoRtOb7wcsrriLaCP7LI5GAlkd5QRqJkTalhoKs1" /><input name="__RequestVerificationToken2" type="hidden" value="__RequestVerificationToken23730970b-0210-41a9-8e66-bda02d908bc1" /> <div class="account signin main-container hide"> <div class="page-content"> <div class="header-section" role="banner"> <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/_static/tfs/M235_20240303.1/_content/Combined.css"> <div id="ux-header" class="FF ltr vsIntegrate" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> <span id="isMobile"></span> <div class="upperBand"> <div class="upperBandContent"> <div class="left"></div> <div class="right"> <div class="profileImage"></div> <div id="signIn"> <a class=":SignedOutProfileElement: createProfileLink" href="/go/profile" title="Anonymous">Anonymous</a> <a class="scarabLink" href="/_signout">Sign out</a> </div> </div> <div class="clear-both"></div> </div> </div> </div> </div> <div class="content-section" role="main"> <div class="signin-main-content"> <noscript> <span class="error">Microsoft Internet Explorer&#39;s Enhanced Security Configuration is currently enabled on your environment. This enhanced level of security prevents our web integration experiences from displaying or performing correctly. To continue with your operation please disable this configuration or contact your administrator.</span> </noscript> <div class="provider-control"> <script class="options" defer="defer" type="application/json">{"providerOptions":{"force":false,"orgIdAuthUrl":"https://login.microsoftonline.com/528e5402-5360-438b-a03f-6ff3444bd09a/oauth2/authorize?client_id=499b84ac-1321-427f-aa17-267ca6975798\u0026site_id=501454\u0026response_mode=form_post\u0026response_type=code+id_token\u0026redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fspsprodcin2.vssps.visualstudio.com%2F_signedin\u0026nonce=b7ecf939-0b7f-4207-9cca-63369953ab2f\u0026state=realm%3Ddev.azure.com%26reply_to%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fdev.azure.com%252FtestOrgzz%252Ftest%252F_apis%252Fwit%252Fworkitems%252F8%253Fapi-version%253D7.2-preview.3%26ht%3D2%26hid%3Db368bbd6-b7b0-467a-945f-d7725c374479%26nonce%3Db7ecf939-0b7f-4207-9cca-63369953ab2f\u0026resource=https%3A%2F%2Fmanagement.core.windows.net%2F\u0026cid=b7ecf939-0b7f-4207-9cca-63369953ab2f\u0026wsucxt=1","user":null,"signInContext":"eyJodCI6MiwiaGlkIjoiN2ZlNDA4NGUtZTg4MS00YjBjLWFkNTUtZmYxOWIwMTg0OTlmIiwicXMiOnsicmVhbG0iOiJkZXYuYXp1cmUuY29tIiwicmVwbHlfdG8iOiJodHRwczovL2Rldi5henVyZS5jb20vdGVzdE9yZ3p6L3Rlc3QvX2FwaXMvd2l0L3dvcmtpdGVtcy84P2FwaS12ZXJzaW9uPTcuMi1wcmV2aWV3LjMiLCJodCI6IjIiLCJoaWQiOiJiMzY4YmJkNi1iN2IwLTQ2N2EtOTQ1Zi1kNzcyNWMzNzQ0NzkiLCJub25jZSI6ImI3ZWNmOTM5LTBiN2YtNDIwNy05Y2NhLTYzMzY5OTUzYWIyZiJ9LCJyciI6IiIsInZoIjoiIiwiY3YiOiIiLCJjcyI6IiJ90"}}</script> </div> </div> </div> </div> <script type="text/javascript">if (window.performance && window.performance.mark) { window.performance.mark('startLoadBundleOuter-common'); }</script> <script data-bundlelength="217072" data-bundlename="common" data-includedscripts="VSS/Bundling" src="/_public/_Bundling/Content?bundle=vss-bundle-common-vR29TkV-17-bwSKtFVO6MaURA35MiJY5Zsze5BA4VMXY=" type="text/javascript"></script> <script type="text/javascript">if (window.performance && window.performance.mark) { window.performance.mark('endLoadBundleOuter-common'); }</script> <script type="text/javascript">if (window.performance && window.performance.mark) { window.performance.mark('startLoadBundleOuter-view'); }</script> <script data-bundlelength="158653" data-bundlename="view" data-includedscripts="Authentication/Scripts/SPS.Authentication.Controls;Authentication/Scripts/SPS.Authentication" src="/_public/_Bundling/Content?bundle=vss-bundle-view-v_jX79q9C-tQaaE-PqtHzcCrvEtl3XJp6y7RcLisV0Do=" type="text/javascript"></script> <script type="text/javascript">if (window.performance && window.performance.mark) { window.performance.mark('endLoadBundleOuter-view'); }</script> <script type="text/javascript"> if (window.performance && window.performance.mark) { window.performance.mark('requireStart'); } require(["Authentication/Scripts/SPS.Authentication.Controls","Authentication/Scripts/SPS.Authentication"], function(){ if (window.performance && window.performance.mark) { window.performance.mark('requireEnd'); } window.requiredModulesLoaded=true; }); </script> </body> </html>



I registered one Azure AD application and granted vso.work permission as below:

Now, I generated one bearer token using authorization code flow via Postman like this:
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/<temamtId>/oauth2/v2.0/token
grant_type:authorization_code
client_id: <appId>
client_secret: <secret>
scope:499b84ac-1321-427f-aa17-267ca6975798/.default
code:code
redirect_uri: https://jwt.ms

Response:

When I used this token to call Azure DevOps API, I got response with work item details successfully:
GET https://dev.azure.com/demodevOps25/demoproj/_apis/wit/workitems/1?api-version=7.2-preview.3

Response:


In your case, the error might occur if third-party application access via OAuth is disabled for your DevOps organization.

To resolve the error, enable third-party application access via OAuth in your organization like this:

Reference:
Suddenly all Azure DevOps APIs giving 401 error - Microsoft Community Hub by heenachauhan

hi i just enabled the third party application access in organization settings.. Working fine

Glad to know it worked :)

In the error message, the user shows as aaaaaaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaaaaaaaaaa which indicates you are not passing correct token for the api.
Please double confirm you are able to access the target work item from DevOps website. To avoid mistake, please regenerate the personal access token.
You can use below script to get the work item details:
# Define parameters
$token = "yourPAT"
$organization = "orgname"
$workItemID = "498"     # your work item id
$uri = "https://dev.azure.com/$organization/_apis/wit/workitems/$workItemID"+"?api-version=7.2-preview.3"

echo $uri    # double check the uri.

# Create authorization header
$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes((":$($token)")))
$headers = @{Authorization=("Basic $base64AuthInfo")}

# Send request
$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Method Get -ContentType "application/json" -Headers $headers | ConvertTo-Json

# Output work item details
echo $response

Work item details:


I have updated the access token and its valid, but it says i do not have the access to the resources

As per your reply above, actually you are not using PAT for authentication.  Glad to know it works after you enable third-party application access via OAuth in organization settings.
